# Merge a dataframe with itself where foreign key refers to its key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
  p_id  val p2_id
0   P1    1    P2
1   P2    2    P3
2   P3    3    P2
3   P4    4    P3
4   P5    5    P1
```

I want to get the `val` that corresponds to `p_id` for each id in `p2_id`, like so:

```
  p_id  val p2_id  val2
0   P1    1    P2     2
1   P2    2    P3     3
2   P3    3    P2     2
3   P4    4    P3     3
4   P5    5    P1     1
```

I have tried to merge the dataframe to itself, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'p_id':  ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5'],
                    'val':   [1,2,3,4,5],
                    'p2_id': ['P2', 'P3', 'P2', 'P3', 'P1'],
                    })
pd.merge(dfa, dfa.drop(columns='p2_id').rename(columns={'p_id':'p2_id'}), on='p2_id', how='left')
```

but this seems like a hacky method. Is there a built-in method for this, or a name for this type of operation?

Comment: did this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`

```
df['val2'] = df.p2_id.map(df.set_index('p_id').val)
```

---

```
  p_id  val p2_id  val2
0   P1    1    P2     2
1   P2    2    P3     3
2   P3    3    P2     2
3   P4    4    P3     3
4   P5    5    P1     1
```